# there is a button and the path of the selected file is transferred to text when I save that data is not transferred to the grid

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I am trying to transfer the data entered in the TextBoxes to gridcontrol. There is no problem when I write to the text manually, but I have a button on the grid, but there is a button and the path of the selected file is transferred to the text. Why would that be? How can I solve it?

I'd appreciate it if you helped.

Thank you.

```
    public frmYazdir(TblBilgi tbl)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        db = new DbEntities1();

        if (tbl != null)
        {
            tblBilgiBindingSource.DataSource = tbl;
        }

    } 

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog DosyaYukle = new OpenFileDialog();
        DosyaYukle.Filter = "REPX Dosyaları(*repx.*) | *.repx*";
        if (DosyaYukle.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filename = DosyaYukle.FileName;
            textBox1.Text = filename;
            if (tbl != null)
            {
            db.TblBilgi.Attach(tblBilgiBindingSource.DataSource as TblBilgi);
            }
        }
    }

 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Kaydedildi.");
    }
```

Comment: Please share some code piece.

Comment: "...but there is a button and the path of the selected file is transferred to the text." I don't understand...maybe reword that sentence?

Answer (score 0):

```
  public frmYazdir(TblBilgi tbl)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        db = new DbEntities1();

        if (tbl != null)
        {
            tblBilgiBindingSource.DataSource = tbl;
        }
    } 
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog DosyaYukle = new OpenFileDialog();
        DosyaYukle.Filter = "REPX Dosyaları(*repx.*) | *.repx*";
        if (DosyaYukle.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filename = DosyaYukle.FileName;
            textBox1.Text = filename;
            if (tbl != null)
            {
                db.TblBilgi.Attach(tblBilgiBindingSource.DataSource as TblBilgi);
            }
        }
    }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Kaydedildi.");
    }
```